# How can I post the label

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on sending the following string as HTML content to a component to use it as an inner HTML content:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var value;


 //Component definition

  html:  '<% using (Html.BeginForm("archExp", "Explorer", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Submit" })) { %> <p> Please specify Directory name</p> 
    <label for="name">Name:</label> <%=  Html.TextBox("name") %> <br /><br /> 
    <label for="name">Parent:'+value+' </label>  
    <div class="form-actions"> <button type="submit" class="t-button">Submit !</button></div> <% } %>'
```

The form contained in the previous HTML string has to POST the text filled inside the textBox as well as the **value** appears in label element, but it's not doing that?!?

**P.S. archExp is the view and Explorer is the controller**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only post input types (not counting querystring values).  Label is not an input type.  Therefore, you can't post a label.

You could save the data in a hidden input field, as well as placing it in the label.